# Does conda build support building a debug version of a package?

Tags: conda

Conda is used to package many C++ libraries. It supports this with a meta.yaml and build.sh recipe.

However, sometimes it would be helpful to build a debug version. Would a debug version need to be a wholly seperate package / recipe? Or is there some built in support for this?

Comment: I have a hunch that this could be done using debug as a feature in [`track_features`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#track-features). I have never tried that myself, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: I think I realize this question is pretty dumb. A debug version of a library needs to refer to the C++ source, and typically a conda package will not distribute the C++ code, it will just have the shared library. Maybe conda is not the best vehicle for C++ debug.

Comment: No reason it couldn't have debug symbols etc.